# Touchpad - Two finger scroll not working

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, touchpad, libinput

I have an ASUS N750JV laptop with kubuntu 18.04 installed and I am struggling to make two finger scroll work. Be default libinput is installed as touchpad driver.
This is the output of `xinput -list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This is the output of `xinput list-props 14`

```
Device 'PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse':
    Device Enabled (175):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (177): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (312):       0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (313):       0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (314):        0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (315):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (316):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (317): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (318): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (319):        0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (320):        0
    libinput Accel Speed (321):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (322):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (323):        1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (324):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (325):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (326):     0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (327):     0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (297):     1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (298):        0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (299):        0, 0
    Device Node (300):      "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (301):        2, 1
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (328):       <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (329):       1
```

I have set the following options to the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Tapping" "true" 
        Option "ClickMethod" "clickfinger"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
        Option "ScrollMethod" "twofinger"
EndSection
```

But still doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please post `dmesg` output and content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` after you booted?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the mouse and touchpad menu in the system settings and make sure that two finger scroll is enabled.

Comment: When I open the Touchpad Settings I got the message "No touchpad found".